# How to implement Google DFP Ads (NativeContentAdView) on Fragment ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I have DetailPage Activity that contain ViewPager. Each page on ViewPage is a fragment (DetailPage Fragment)

I want to add NativeContentAdView on DetailPage Fragment, but the problem is sometime the ad not loaded yet and ViewPager being swipe (and replaced by new fragment), so ads rarely show.

Any tips about using DFP Ad on Fragment ViewPager?
Or maybe link that explain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, load your ad and store it somewhere not in your UI fragment. I recommend a retained fragment. Then, implement a callback from the fragment where you'd like to show an ad (i.e. DetailPageFragment) that asks for the ads to display.

Example: (I don't know if this compiles; it's more pseudocode)

```
public class DetailPageFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface AdRequestListener {
         void onAdRequestedForDisplay();
    }
    ...
    public void onAdLoaded(NativeAd ad) {
      // Display ad here
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       // Set listener
    }

    public void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listener.onAdRequestedForDisplay();
    }
 }

public class AdLoadingFragment extends Fragment {
    private NativeAd ad;

    public interface AdLoadListener {
        void onAdLoaded(NativeAd ad);
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        try {
           this.listener = (AdLoadListener) activity;
        } catch(ClassCastException cce) {
          throw new RuntimeException(activity.toString() + " must implement AdLoadListener");
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            requestAd();
         }
    }

    private void requestAd() {
        //Request ad

        //Notify listener when ad is loaded
    }

    public void onAdRequested() {
        if(ad != null && listener != null) {
            listener.onAdLoaded(ad);
        }
    }
    ...
```

}